# How to transform a Map by changing its values?

Tags: kotlin

I need to hash all values in a map and return the same type of map.

My solution looks very wonky at the moment:

```
val hashedPolicies = policyProperties.map { it.key to it.value.hash() }.toMap()
```

Without the `toMap()`, it returns a `List` which is not acceptable.

Is there a better way of creating a new map of a map like this (without having to use `.toMap()`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`mapValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html):

> ```
> inline fun <K, V, R> Map<out K, V>.mapValues(
>     transform: (Entry<K, V>) -> R
> ): Map<K, R>
> ```
>
> **Returns** a new map with entries having the keys of this map and the values obtained by applying the transform function to each entry in this Map.
>
> The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original map.
> <sub>[kotlin-stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) / [kotlin.collections](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) / [mapValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html)</sub>

```
val test = mapOf("foo" to "bar")
println(test)
// {foo=bar}

val result = test.mapValues { it.value.hashCode() }
println(result)
// {foo=97299}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fold to do everything in one go:

```
val hashedPolicies = policyProperties.entries.fold(mutableMapOf<KeyType, Int>{ map, it ->
    map.put(it.key, it.value.hashCode())
    map
}
```

While `mapValues` is more specific and suitable for this specific case, `fold` as less specific level method has the advantage to work on all [iterable](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/index.html) and array types. Also it allows you to use an arbitrary return type.