how to transform HashMap<Int,List<IntArray>> to HashMap<Int,List<Int>> in kotlin
For example,I have a HashMap<Int,List> which contains
1 to {[2,1],[3,1],[4,1]} , then I want to use a high-order function to transform this map to HashMap<Int,List> format like 1 to {2,3,4}, so how to write a kotlin code to transform the map. Thank you so much.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53534868/how-to-transform-a-map-by-changing-its-values

I'm not exactly sure what is the expected transformation. How did the list of arrays became a flat list? Do you need to get the first item of each array?

You can use mapValues on your map to change the values:
yourMap.mapValues { entry ->
    entry.value.map { it[0] }
}

Each list's content was an array and is now the first value of that array.
